# Разыскивается годный роутер для node.js

Tags: node.js, маршрутизация, поиск-библиотек

Разыскивается вменяемый годный роутер. Отличительные признаки:

- размер не более 50-100 строк, строго ES6.
- написан просто, чтобы человек с улицы сразу смог разобраться как все работает.
- не использует сторонних библиотек, кроме встроенных в node.js.
- имеет возможность строить независимые последовательные цепочки middleware для каждого отдельного роута.
- middleware разделены на отдельные цепочки входящих и исходящих (request и response).
- не содержит всякого мусора, типа шаблонизаторов, заточен только на REST.
- умеет шаблоны url типа /foo/:bar.

Синтаксис нужен типа такого:

```
router.addRoute({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/foo/:bar"
  middlewares: {
    request: [
      (req) => {
        ...
        return req;
      },
      (req) => {
        ...
        return req;
      },
      (req) => {
        ...
        return req;
      },
    ],
    response: [
      (res) => {
        ...
        return res;
      },
      (res) => {
        ...
        return res;
      },
      (res) => {
        ...
        return res;
      },
    ],
  },
  handler: (req, res) => {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Этот вопрос немного не по теме сайта. Но если нужно - существует очень популярный [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)

Comment: Express увы не подойдёт. Он не удовлетворяет моих требований, изложенных в сообщении.